# Why does SimulatorTrampoline.xpc request access to my main Documents folder?

Tags: ios-simulator

It alarms me that SimulatorTrampoline.xpc requested access to the main Documents folder of my Mac.

Nothing in my app code requires such access. So why is the simulator attempting to access my main Documents folder. Is it possible the simulator has been hacked?

Can I find out what process on the iOS simulator initiated this request?